# React :use image as link

Tags: reactjs

How do I make an image clickable in react, I tried these two methods

the first one does not work at all

```
{ this.state.posts.map((post) => {
   return (  
    <div class="col-md-6 col-6 padding animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
       <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2">
        <Link to={`/Post/${post.id}`}>
         <img src={post.image} />
        </Link>
       </div>
```

as for this one, I apparently need to import {image} from react-native but when I install react native I get this error :

ERROR in `./node_modules/react-native/index.js`

react-native Module parse failed

```
{ this.state.posts.map((post) => {
  return (
   <div class="col-md-6 col-6 paddding animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
   <div class="fh5co_suceefh5co_height_2">
     <Link to={`/Post/${post.id}`}>
       <Image src={post.image} />
     </Link>
   </div>
```

Comment: Are you developing for web (react-dom) or mobile (react-native)?

Comment: for web (react-dom)

Comment: Ok, so then you shouldn't use `react-native` and thus have no access to the `<Image>` element which is mobile only. Your first sample is more correct. What exactly is the problem with the first version?

Comment: the images apear normally but are not clickable.edit: btw the link works with text

Comment: Can you see the `<a>` element in the rendered html?

Comment: tried it like this but also not clickable 
 <a href={`/Post/${post.id}`}>
  <img src={post.image}  width="500" height="400"/>
 </a>

Comment: That is correct. Link should be clickable, the reason must be outside the code you have provided

Comment: yup i started deleting stuff, turns out it was a css class causing the problem. thanks.